# Is there a direct access to raw numpy bytes? The term "direct" here means "without making a copy"

Tags: python, numpy

In documentation, I only found `numpy.ndarray.tobytes`. However, in other languages like Java I used to have direct access to the internal memory of matrices in math libraries, avoiding making a copy.

Comment: Why do you need "direct access"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: It depends on what you are planning to do with the bytes. Maybe you can tell us more so we can help better?

Comment: I just prefer not to delay the access making an unneeded copy. The bytes will not be changed, just read-only used for a lot of fast things billions of times. So avoiding a copy makes sense.

Comment: Would it make sense for your process to set the dtype when you create the array? Eg a = np.arange(10), dtype=np.bytes_)

Comment: `arr.data` is a `memoryview` of the array `arr`.  https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.data.html#numpy.ndarray.data.  It conforms to a Python `buffer` standard.  But generally `python/numpy` users don't work with it directly.  Only cross language (e.g. `c` level) programmers use it.  Working with that buffer directly in Python code would be incredibly slow.